# bug in generating output file in R

Tags: r, loops, output

I am trying to write my output to a txt file that meets the following format requirement:

```
user_id \t brand_id , brand_id , brand_id \n
```

"\t" and "\n" here are to insert tab space and change line.
Right now I have `2` lists, `user_id` and `brand_id` and a `binary matrix C`, that each row corresponds to the `id` in `user_id` list in the same order, column correspond to `brand_id` in the same manner. `If C[i,j]=1`, it means I need to write out `brand_id[j]` on the row of `user_id[i]`. 
I wrote the following code, but it generates the output below that is incorrect.  The `"\"` distance between `user_id` and `brand_id` is too wide for most rows. Can anyone help me correct this?

```
sink("result.txt")
for (i in 1:nrow(C)){
  temp <- which(C[i,]==1)
  if(length(temp)==1){
    cat(user_id[i])
    cat(" \t ")
    cat(brand_id[temp])
    cat("\n")
  }else if(length(temp)>1){
    cat(user_id[i])
    cat(" \t ")
    for (j in 1:(length(temp)-1)){
      cat(brand_id[j])
      cat(" , ")
    }
    cat(brand_id[temp[length(temp)]])
    cat("\n")
  }
}
sink()
```

A partial of the output from @jbaums' code and my above code was like this

```
8649250      28481  
887500   4571
```

It seems 1 digit less in user_id creates a significant less space between user_id and brand_id. I checked the visual effect in both MAC and windows using VI and TXT editor, identical. Does this was caused by more depth bug I was not aware? Thanks

Comment: So the only issue is the number of spaces? If the number of spaces in `\t` is too much, you can just do `cat('   ')` or whatever meets your requirements. You have an extra space on either side of the `\t` as well.

Comment: even having a few lines of `C`, `user_id` and `brand_id` would help along with a few lines of actual output you are looking for, even if both examples are files linked to in dropbox or some other type of service.

Comment: It is required that there is a \t between user_id and first brand_id

Comment: In regards to your recent edit, are you sure it's not just the way that your editors render tab characters? Notepad++ does indeed present the first tab (after 8649250) as being longer than the tab after 887500, but `View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters` reveals they are in fact both tabs. Further, treating the file as tab-delimited in Excel separates out the first column as you'd expect.

Comment: OK, thanks for your explanation. I think the output should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your data and your requirements, there are simpler ways to achieve this.

By assigning the `user_id` vector as row names of `C`, and the `brand_id` vector as the column names, you can do something like this:

```
set.seed(1)    
C <- matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), nc=10, nr=10, 
            dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:10],
                          letters[1:10]))

invisible(sapply(seq_len(nrow(C)), function(i) {
  if(sum(C[i, ]) > 0) {
    cat(rownames(C)[i], '\t', 
        paste(colnames(C)[C[i, ]==1], collapse=' , '), ' \n') 
  }
}))


A    c , e , g  
B    f , h  
D    a , j  
E    d  
F    a , h  
G    a , h  
H    b  
I    c , j  
J    g , h
```

Use `sink` either side as required.

Comment: it seems your code did not skip the rows that are all 0. I will try to add an if statement inside your function for my own code

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: I carefully checked your beautiful code, indeed it generates the same output as my original code. Please see my updated original post.