# build index tables based on data frame content in R

Tags: r, data-binding

I have a data frame A with the following format:

```
user item
101    1  
101    2  
101    4  
102    2  
103    3
103    4
...    ...
```

I want to create 2 data frame B and C

```
user itemList
101   c(1,2,4)  
102   c(2)
103   c(3,4)


item  userList
1     c(101)
2     c(101,102)
3     c(103)
4     c(101,103)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want `itemList` to contain? Vectors with multiple elements, or a comma-separated string? Also, this question seems _very) similar to your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754432/r-output-to-txt-file) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571163/bug-in-generating-output-file-in-r). Have you tried anything along the lines of what was suggested in their solutions? The following will generate lists that might serve the purpose: `tapply(d$item, d$user, c); tapply(d$user, d$item, c)`.

Comment: @jbaums, if I use your solution, how to find the length of userList for item,  say item 1 and item 2?  Right now your solution return 1 for both cases. Thanks

Comment: Never mind, I think I can use @chit's solution

Comment: You can use `sapply(tapply(d$user, d$item, c), length)` to return a vector giving the number of users corresponding to each item, and `sapply(tapply(d$item, d$user, c), length)` to return the number of items for each user.

Comment: Thanks. How to extract 102 from item 2 userList in this case?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to unlink item 2 and user 102? (i.e. do you want to delete user 102 from item 2?) If so, try: `items <- tapply(d$user, d$item, c)`, then `items[['2']] <- items[['2']][items[['2']] != 102]`.

Comment: No, I need to calculate the similarity of items using Jaccard's distance. But meanwhile I need to be able to refer to specific element of the list. So in your solution, how should I access the user 102 in item 2?

Comment: Standard list subsetting. For list `L`, e.g. `L <- tapply(d$user, d$item, c)`, you can access the second element with `L[[2]]`, and the element with name "2" with `L[['2']]`. So the element in question is referred to with `L[['2']][grep(102, L[['2']])]`. Similarly, for list `L <- tapply(d$item, d$user, c)`, you can subset to item 4 in the element corresponding to user 103 with `L[['103']][grep(4, L[['103']])]`. I don't really know what you mean by "access", though.

Comment: Thanks. But I might feel confused, your current solution might make my similarity calculation difficult.  Let me define the similarity between two userLists as number of intersection elements divided by total number of distinct elements in two userLists, how would you proceed?  You can use Item 2 and Item 4 's userLists for example.

Comment: Ah, ok. For that I would probably do: `sapply(L, function(x) sapply(L, function(y) {
  length(intersect(x, y)) / length(union(x, y))
}))`. This basically says "for each element of L (i.e. each userList), compare with each element of L. Calculate the number of intersecting elements divided by the number of total unique elements."

Comment: I am from Java and Python background, I feel sapply usage might be more like functional programming in scala. I think I have long way to go to master R.  Thanks for your patient answers to R newbie:)

Comment: @jbaums, if I want to loop over all items and establish the pairwise similarity matrix based on the similarity definition I mentioned above. How should I avoid the loop here?  Thanks

Comment: The code in my most recent comment should do just that. It returns that matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr package for this

```
library(dplyr)

user.grp <- df %.%
  group_by(user) %.%
  summarise(itemList=paste(item,collapse=','))

#output
user.grp
#  user itemList
#1  101    1,2,4
#2  102        2
#3  103      3,4
```

similarly you can use item in group_by for group by items.

If the requirement is to have the grouped data as vector of numbers, then we need to store the entire data in list.

```
library(plyr)
dlply(df,.(user),function(df){df$item})

#output
#$`101`
#[1] 1 2 4

#$`102`
#[1] 2

#$`103`
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: Note, though, that `itemList` is now a vector of character strings with items separated by commas, rather than each element of `itemList` being a vector of items as implied in the question.

Comment: then, in this case we need to store the grouped data in a list.

Comment: ;) yep, as I alluded to in my comment on the question.